# How can I start a hyper.sh container via the API? (receiving 'exec failed: no such file or directory error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I'm building a JS grading app using hyper.sh.  When I create a container via the API, specified commands are not run when I try to start it (via API or CLI).  Instead `'exec failed: no such file or directory` is written to the logs.

I start by using axios to create a container based on the /containers/create documentation.  I shortened some of the contents here, but it's the same body provided in the docs.

```
var createOptions = {
  url: 'https://us-west-1.hyper.sh/containers/create',
  method: 'POST',
  credential: {
       accessKey: '...',
       secretKey: '...'
  },
  body: {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Cmd":[
      "date"
    ],
    "Entrypoint": "",
    "Image": "ubuntu",
    "Labels": {
      "com.example.vendor": "Acme",
      "com.example.license": "GPL",
      "com.example.version": "1.0",
      "sh_hyper_instancetype": "s4"
    },
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "ExposedPorts": {
      "22/tcp": {}
    },
    "StopSignal": "SIGTERM",
    "HostConfig": {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Next, I run hyper start `$(id)`.  The container id is logged, but the command specified in Cmd is not run.  Any ideas what is happening would be appreciated. 
 Thanks for the help.

Comment: yeah, this is definitely a frustrating problem, let me know if you figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be fixed by removing `"Entrypoint": "",` from the container options.

For additional info, it seems as though ENTRYPOINT and CMD are related and using both is redundant.  I made an issue for clarification in the hyper API docs.